# The value supplied for parameter 'instanceProfileName' is not valid

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

Running `cdk deploy` I receive the following error message:

> CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::ImageBuilder::InfrastructureConfiguration | TestInfrastructureConfiguration The value supplied for parameter 'instanceProfileName' is not valid. The provided instance profile does not exist. Please specify a different instance profile and try again. (Service: Imagebuilder, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 41f431d7-8544-48e9-9faf-a870b83b0100, Extended Request ID: null)

The C# code looks like this:

```cs
var instanceProfile = new CfnInstanceProfile(this, "TestInstanceProfile", new CfnInstanceProfileProps {
  InstanceProfileName = "test-instance-profile",
  Roles = new string[] { "TestServiceRoleForImageBuilder" }
});

var infrastructureConfiguration = new CfnInfrastructureConfiguration(this, "TestInfrastructureConfiguration", new CfnInfrastructureConfigurationProps {
  Name = "test-infrastructure-configuration",
  InstanceProfileName = instanceProfile.InstanceProfileName,
  InstanceTypes = new string[] { "t2.medium" },
  Logging = new CfnInfrastructureConfiguration.LoggingProperty {
    S3Logs = new CfnInfrastructureConfiguration.S3LogsProperty {
      S3BucketName = "s3-test-assets",
      S3KeyPrefix = "ImageBuilder/Logs"
    }
  },
  SubnetId = "subnet-12f3456f",
  SecurityGroupIds = new string[] { "sg-12b3e4e5b67f8900f" }
});
```

The **TestServiceRoleForImageBuilder** exists and was working previously. Same code was running successfully about a month ago. Any suggestions?

If I remove the **CfninfrastructureConfiguration** creation part, deployment runs successfully:, but takes at least 2 minutes to complete.

> AwsImageBuilderStack: deploying...
> AwsImageBuilderStack: creating CloudFormation changeset...
> 0/3 | 14:24:37 | REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack | AwsImageBuilderStack User Initiated
> 0/3 | 14:24:43 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack | AwsImageBuilderStack User Initiated
> 0/3 | 14:24:47 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CDK::Metadata        | CDKMetadata/Default (CDKMetadata)
> 0/3 | 14:24:47 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile | TestInstanceProfile
> 0/3 | 14:24:47 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile | TestInstanceProfile Resource creation Initiated
> 1/3 | 14:24:48 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CDK::Metadata        | CDKMetadata/Default (CDKMetadata) Resource creation Initiated
> 1/3 | 14:24:48 | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::CDK::Metadata        | CDKMetadata/Default (CDKMetadata)
> 1/3 Currently in progress: AwsImageBuilderStack, TestInstanceProfile
> 3/3 | 14:26:48 | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile | TestInstanceProfile
> 3/3 | 14:26:49 | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack | AwsImageBuilderStack

Is it probably some race condition? Should I use multiple stacks to achieve my goal?

Should it be possible to use a wait condition [(AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-waitcondition.html) to bypass the 2 minutes of creation time in case it is intended [(AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile resources always take exactly 2 minutes to create)](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=593651)?

#### Environment

- **CDK CLI Version:** 1.73.0
- **Node.js Version:** 14.13.0
- **OS:** Windows 10
- **Language (Version):** C# (.NET Core 3.1)

#### Update

Since the cause seems to be AWS internal, I used a pre-created instance profile as a workaround. The profile can be either created through IAM Management Console or CLI. However it would be nice to have a proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a dependency between the two constructs. CDK does not infer it when using the optional name parameter, as opposed to the logical id (which doesn't seem to work in this situation).

```
infrastructureConfiguration.node.addDependency(instanceProfile)
```

Here are the relevant docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/core-readme.html#construct-dependencies